# How does one unset an array element in ASP classic?

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, unset

Is there an ASP Classic equivalent to PHP `unset(array1[3])` function?

Comment: It would help those of us who don't know PHP to describe what the `unset` function is supposed to do.

Comment: Why use it? In ASP we usuallly use a different variable name for the array once it is split, so there is no need to unarray.

Comment: Unset() in PHP destroys a given variable/array element. For my case, I need to delete an element in the middle of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this will do it, for a numerical array, at least:

```
sub unset(array, index)
   if index < lbound(array) or index > ubound(array) then exit sub

   dim i, move
   move = false
   for i = lbound(array) to ubound(array)
      if i = index then move = true

      if move and i < ubound(array) then
         array(i) = array(i + 1)
      end if
   next

   redim preserve array(i - 2)  
end sub
```